# CSS Full Width Images inside Fixed Containers

Tags: ios, css

Is there any way to ensure that an image is always displayed with full-screen with regardless of what container size constraints are placed on it? In my case I'm receiving from the server a HTML file with images in various different containers of different sizes (usually specified in percentages) and for each image I would like to use CSS to "break out" of the container and always occupy full-screen width.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Can you position the image absolutely? http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/KM4Zj/

Comment: Yes, but when I do this it seems to cause another issue where the image will overlap with the text content it was near. Isn't there anyway to just say to the image to go fully wide without taking it completely out of the stacking context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To 'break them out,' you will need to separate them from the stacking context by applying `img { position: absolute; }` in your CSS. You could then bring them to full window width by applying `img { width: 100%; }` to fill... but you're likely to encounter problems with your layout as a result. You should probably focus on making your wrapping containers full-width within the stacking context of the document, in order to preserve the integrity of your layout (which will be changing here with any route that you end up choosing).

Comment: You would need something like `top:0px; left:0px` .. might also need `height:100%;` or `height:auto`..

Comment: Hi Stuart, as you mention when I add position: absolute I do get other layout problems with the images sometimes obscuring the content. If I can't control the CSS being applied to the other wrapping containers is there no way to solve this?

Comment: There may be hacks... but you'll want to tread carefully with those. These will depend on the remaining items in your layout too, so it's hard to say. Here's one possibility: apply `position: relative;` to the wrapping containers, and that will give you a basis for adding `top: 0; left 0;` to your images, as @JoshC mentions. You could then experiment with adding `overflow: visible;` to those wrappers, and adding negative margins (or some other hacky thing) to the images...

Comment: If you can't alter styling on any element but the images themselves, I tend to believe you're stuck ;)